# Why won't all the data get displayed on the browser even though all data is being displayed in console.log()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I'm using an `$.ajax();` request to make a call to my controller.  Inside the `console.log();`, it's correctly displaying all of the data coming in but when I try to display it on the browser via `$('#displayCoins').text(item.oldCoins);` - only the very last piece of data if being displayed instead of all of the data.

What am I doing wrong and how can I go about rectifying this in terms of displaying all of the data on the browser?

```
               $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/my/endpoint',
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        var resp = response;
                        var respParsed = $.parseJSON(resp);

                        $.each(respParsed, function(i, item) {
                            console.log(item.oldCoins);
                            $('#displayCoins').text(item.oldCoins);
                        });
                       
                    }
                });
```

Comment: on every iteration you replace the content..... It does not keep appending...... Replace the text, next one, replace the text, next one replace the text <-- you get the last one...

Comment: How do you want it displayed? The solution depends on that answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is you are REPLACING the text every time through the loop instead of appending it.

One solution is to append the data to an array, then output it to the DOM via a single join.

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/my/endpoint',
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        var resp = response;
                        var respParsed = $.parseJSON(resp);
                        oldCoins = [];
                        $.each(respParsed, function(i, item) {
                            console.log(item.oldCoins);
                            oldCoins.push(item.oldCoins);
                        });
                        $('#displayCoins').text(oldCoins.join("\n"));
                       
                    }
                });
```

Comment: um, not doing to work... it is text, not html

Comment: @epascarello, I changed it to a different method